# $mdDialog cannot open templateUrl but template works fine

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I am trying to open a dialog with a template inside a .html file using `templateUrl`. However, when the dialog opens, the content of the file looks like it's empty. The background just darkens and nothing appears on the screen. If I do `template: "Test"` instead of my `templateUrl`, it opens a dialog with the text `Test` on it (as it should).

```
$mdDialog.show({
    templateUrl: "Dialogs/Teams/CreateTeamDialog.html",
    controller: "CreateTeamController",
    controllerAs: "vm"
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Woohoo");
});
```

When I open developer tools and I find the network tab, I can see the file being loaded when I open the dialog:

[image]

> Status: 200 OK

To sum it up:

- My file exists
- My file contains some text
- My file is being loaded when I open the dialog
- The dialog works with `template` instead of `templateUrl`

What on earth is going on then?

Answer (score 1):

God dammit... I spent hours upon hours trying to figure this out. Turns out my .html file's content was "empty". All I had to do was remove the flex'd container (because for some reason it was 0px wide).